storyblok-assets-cleanup – The script doesn't create a assets_backup folder
I am not sure exactly how to debug this or find a solution.
Basically, with the help of this script, I am scanning through 60.000 + assets to make a backup and potentially find which ones are not used and can be deleted. Scanning through this amount of items takes about 7 hours. Now, I noticed that after 2 hours, there is still no assets_backup folder created, even with the flag --backup activated.
I set up a virtual environment as suggested, and it creates a cache folder in the local directory but no backup unfortunately. Any ideas how to find the reason for this?
Here is the script:
https://github.com/significa/storyblok-assets-cleanup?tab=readme-ov-file
